# Iterating files in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-9.3, iterator

I want to use around 100 files as input in a model I created in ArcMap 9.3

Do to so I followed the esri help page (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_model_iteration) and right-clicked my input variable to switch it from "A single value" to "A list of values". When I run my model from the toolbox it only offers me list where I have to input each of my files separately. It is not possible to select all my 100 files at once like I can do in ArcMap 10.x when using the "Iterate Feature Classes" tool.

**Is there a way to select a bunch of files as input for a model in ArcMap 9.3 without selecting each file separately?**

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 was recently retired, and 9.x has been retired for a while now. If it works with modern software, that indicates the capability was added later. Since 9.x is long retired, you may find difficulty locating others with 9.x to test for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used 9.3 for many years now. An alternative way to run your model is to right click on it and run in batch mode. You may be able to drag and drop multiple datasets in to the batch grid interface?

I remember looping was awkward in 9.3 and the usual way of resolving things was to write a simple loop in python.